# How can I get the major-mode name of buffer at the cursor in Helm

Tags: helm

I would like to perform some commands after I open a file in helm. For instance, call `imenu` to get a list of headings of opened org-mode buffer. But for some buffers, like `message`, it is not necessary to do that. So if here, the major-mode name or the file name of current selection in helm can be obtained, it will be much easy to call conditional subsequent commands.

like:

```
(defun call-imenu-after-helm () 
    (interactive)
    (helm-for-files)
    (when "a condition to say this buffer is a org file"
       (helm-imenu)
       (org-show-entry)))
```

I asked help in github and google plus, but it seems like that the function has not been implemented in helm for now.

Can anyone get some good ideas to do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like adding a new `imenu` action to the `helm-buffers-list` command if current selection is a org-mode file?

Comment: @xuchunyang thanks for response. Yes.

Comment: I think the answer to your question (in title) will not help you. There are many commands provided by the helm package, not all of them are about buffers of files, for example, `helm-imenu` and `helm-show-kill-ring`, it can be anything at the cursor in helm. Did you ever try to make a helm command yourself?

Comment: a simple demo: https://gist.github.com/xuchunyang/9296e3d1469416124bcb

Comment: Hi, @xuchunyang thanks for your comments. I will study your snippet.